# Accessing External document from a repository

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex, apex, oracle-apex-5.1

How can i access documents from a repository(my server) through oracle apex.

Scenario. i have scanned documents saved on my server and i want to create a report where i can use a link via the url to access the document. I have been trying to  use the document part(server address) but its not working. Its not opening the folder on the server.

my part is `\\ag.ag.gov.tt\Information and Communications Technology Unit\Weekly Reports`.

I have a test table

```
select ID,
       NAME,
       POSITION,
       URL
  from USERS
```

where the url will be.

Comment: Hi, I think you can read the files from directory as clob and download it in Oracle Apex. Create a directory in the DB and place the files in the location. You can add file name and file mime type columns in the table.  Call the procedure to read the files and download it in Oracle Apex.

Comment: For static content, it is better to place the files on a web server or some other web-enabled storage and place links to the files in APEX. You will get better performance than serving them as CLOBs or BLOBs from the database. You will generally not not be able to serve the files from a remote file share.

Comment: i think i will try the web server because i am trying to get away from the limited space issue